# Integrating Spring 4 with Struts 1.2

Tags: spring-mvc, struts-1

I currently have an application with Struts 1.2 and Spring 2.5. I am looking to upgrade Spring to latest version so I can use the new features such Spring boot and Spring MVC for implementing RESTful services using Spring.

When upgraded to Spring 4, how can I ensure that my application still works well with Struts 1.2? Is there any option where with minimal or no changes, upgradinbng spring library works with Struts 1.2 application?

Kindly help.

Comment: Struts 1 support in Spring has been deprecated since Spring 3, and removed in Spring 4. If the apps are running in *parallel* you might be able to shade Spring 2.5's dependencies and run the S1 app "as-is".